# Aggregate initialization of class with noncopyable member

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate-initialization

Suppose I have some class with deleted copy constructor:

```
struct NoCopy
{
    NoCopy(int) {}
    NoCopy(const NoCopy &) = delete;
};
```

I use this class in another class:

```
struct Aggregate
{
    NoCopy nc;
};
```

But when I'm trying to use aggregate initialization

```
int main()
{
    Aggregate a{3};
}
```

Compiler outputs the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘NoCopy::NoCopy(const NoCopy&)’
```

Why does aggregate initialization requires copy constructors of class's members? Does aggregate initialization initialize all members using copy constructors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax for what you want is:

```
Aggregate a{{3}};
```

This provides an initializer for the `NoCopy` member. Without the extra `{}` the compiler needs to perform a conversion from `int` to `NoCopy` (which it happily does via the non-explicit constructor), and then use that to construct `nc`.  This would normally occur as a move construction but by deleting the copy ctor you have effictively deleted the move constructor as well.

An easier way to think about it might be to imagine `NoCopy` had a value constructor taking two arguments instead of one:

```
struct NoCopy {
    NoCopy(int, int);
};
```

Now if you wrote

```
Aggregate a{1, 2};
```

that would indicate that `1` is used to initialize `nc` and `2` is used to initialize something else (compile-time error).  You'd have to add the extra `{}` for this to make sense

```
Aggregate a{{1, 2}};
```

A third way involves looking at a function call:

```
struct NoCopy {
  NoCopy(int) {}
  NoCopy(const NoCopy &) = delete;
};

void fun(NoCopy) { }

int main() {
  fun(1); // wrong
  fun({1}); // right
}
```

In the `// wrong` version, a temporary `NoCopy` object is constructed at the callsite using the `NoCopy(int)` constructor. Then that temporary is passed by value into `fun`, but since `NoCopy` isn't copyable, it fails.

In the `// right` version you are providing the initializer list for the argument to be constructed with. No copies are made.

Comment: Thank you, it works. So, the answer to the question is very easy, but it's hard to understand that from compiler's message.

Comment: Btw, compiler elides all copying here anyway. So if I declare copy constructor in `NoCopy` class, it isn't called, compiler calls `NoCopy(int)` directly anyway.

Comment: @anton_rh yes the error you get is a couple of steps away from where the problem starts

Comment: @anton_rh right but even if it elides the copy it still has to be legal for the copy to occur, the alternative would be a disaster.